# django form to contain stackoverflow-style tag input

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

How would you go about creating a form that contains this type of input? It would need to be able to handle multiple inputs (undefined number), so what sort of field do you use?

Answer (score 0):

It's a [typeahead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typeahead) variant. There are many 'how-to's and freebies on the web. You'll need a basic understanding of HTML forms and Javascript.

Here's a popular example by Twitter: [Bootstrap Typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead)